# Manually adding a DKIM header

Tags: email, vbscript, dkim, jmail, mailenable

Forgive the noob question, but up until yesterday I didn't even know what a DKIM was.

We are using Windows Server 2008 R2 and mailEnable 5.51 Standard Edition as an out going only SMTP. This is only used by JMail form to email traffic.

I'm trying to cut down on the amount out outgoing emails being classed as spam by customers email clients or by people like gmail, hotmail, AOL etc.

I was advised to consider setting up DKIM and pointed in the direction of https://www.socketlabs.com/domainkey-dkim-generation-wizard/ to generate a key.

For example, for domain : somedomain.com, selector : key1

Which give me the following:

```
Name    Value
_domainkey.somedomain.com   t=y;o=~;
key1._domainkey.somedomain.com  k=rsa;     p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDAzmaNvSCwQX+jO/9SmZyA7Eg3W269ZqIdPxV1su9vXvN5Wac1gZpEpogS9CPe5TeWtTx/yph2niB88NuDOx0wX54529XLiRxanc6gZDMsE6+p+DYqpNV2Hi4VPusWl9zlrLo5ySfSLE7sKmzqKx1JCOBJ7sWzY/i0+dc4Bfq9VwIDAQAB
```

This bit I'm ok with, and understand about adding the TXT records to the domains DNS.

The problem I'm having is what to do with the private key.

I understand mailEnable does support DKIM but you have to upgrade to a newer Enterprise Edition, which we are not in the market for at the moment.

But, because I convert the forms to email myself using classic .asp (VB.Script) and construct the emails using JMail can't I use something like:

```
AddHeader('key', 'value')
```

To manually create the private DKIM header needed to complete the system?
If so, how do I go from the data in the private key to the DKIM headers required in the emails header?

Comment: I removed the private key from your question.  There's a reason it's called "private", you know.  It's too late now to put the cat back in the bag, though; you will need to ditch the leaked key and create a new one.

Comment: This is too thin to put in an answer; but I doubt you will receive any more substantial answers.  As the answer to your direct question; Sure, if you know what goes in the `value` part; but that's the hard part.
You will basically have to implement the relevant part of the DKIM signing algorithms yourself. Maybe for a start read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail

Comment: Hi Tripleee. Not to worry, the code I generated was not for a real domain, it was just as an example. I might have found a possible solution in the form of DKeyEvent http://mailenable.exhalus.net/domainkeys/. I'm going to look into that. Thanks for your help.